# Wordpress php query more than 1 table in the database

Tags: wordpress

I have a query where i need to access information from different tables that are related by ID's to get the necessary information. This is what the code looks like, I was wonder if there is a more efficient way to write the code?

```
<?php 
global $wpdb;
$eventlist = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM wp_events_detail LIMIT 3 ", $id ), OBJECT );
foreach ( $eventlist as $event ) {
    $get_team_id = $event->id;
    $startdate = $event->start_date;
    $enddate = $event->end_date;
    echo  '<div class="span3">';
    echo  '<h3>' .$event->event_name. '</h3>';
    echo ''.date("l", strtotime($startdate)).'<br />';
    echo date("F", strtotime($startdate));
    echo $event->venue_title;

    /* GET START AND END TIME */
        $event_times = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM wp_events_start_end WHERE event_id = %d", $get_team_id ), OBJECT );
        foreach ( $event_times as $event_time ) {
            $start_time = $event_time->start_time;
            $end_time   = $event_time->end_time;

            echo '<strong>' . date("g:i", strtotime($start_time)) . '</strong><small>' . date("a", strtotime($start_time)) . '</small> > ';
            echo '<strong>' . date("g:i", strtotime($end_time)) . '</strong><small>' . date("a", strtotime($end_time)) . '</small>';
        }

        /* Get Venue Name */
        $event_venue = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM wp_events_venue_rel WHERE event_id = %d", $get_team_id ), OBJECT );
        foreach ( $event_venue as $venue ) {
            $venue_id = $venue->venue_id;                               
            $ts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM wp_events_venue WHERE id = %d", $venue_id ), OBJECT );
            foreach ( $ts as $t ) {
                echo $t->name;
            }
        }
    echo  '</div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a **much** more efficient way. Look at JOIN in MySQL [here](http://mysqljoin.com/joins/inner-join-tutorial/) or [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx) or [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)